# In rails I need to store path information when creating an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, audit-logging

Suppose I have two controllers: `api/x/posts` and `api/y/posts`

both controllers have a create method which creates a post model.

I want to be able to easily see which controller created the model.

My idea was to use a callback to set a "path" attribute inside model:

```
def set_path
  self.path = request.path
end
```

However this is discouraged because it breaks mvc principle. So what would be a clean way of doing this?

Comment: Models should have no idea about the controllers, so, while there are ways to do it, as you said, it completely breaks the MVC design. What is your use case for doing this?

Comment: The use case is basically logging/auditing. I want to be able to see how a post was created  after it's created.

Comment: Also  I don't want to set the value of post.path in my controller because every dev would have to remember to do that in every new controller

Comment: What about a `before_action` in your application controller that does that automatically? That removes the need for every dev to remember to do it.

Comment: before_action is called before the model is instantiated, so how can I set the path attribute there?

Answer (score 0):

(Based on the OP's additional comment that they're actually auditing)

Instead of adding noise to your model table, you should actually use an auditing gem, they'll give you the ability to either add an arbitrary comment when calling the model's write method, or add some additional meta-data in some other way.

Comment: We do use the audited gem, but couldn't find a way to easily add path to audit log. But perhaps I can Extend the Audited module and add a request_path method the same way as request_uid method here: https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited/blob/379aeed7c22a530da0effa2b6b790ad806c5b7a1/lib/audited/sweeper.rb#L30

Comment: So I figured out you could add the path to the audit log with the audited gem by defining your own custom audit class that extends audited::audit like this:

```ruby
class MyAudit < Audited::Audit
    before_create :set_request_path
    
    private

    def set_request_path
        self.request_path = ::Audited.store[:current_controller].request.path}
    end
end
```

I however fail to see how this is different than just calling request.path in your rails model? All this seems to do is add a few layers of ambiguity

Comment: It's very clear to me that the audit information of which endpoint a post was created from has nothing to do with the post itself, so doesn't belong in the `Post` table, I assumed you also realized there was something off about storing that information in the `Post` - which was why you asked your question. If you think it belongs in the `Post` then go for it.